# How to set DropDown multi select values in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want Drop Down Multi select values are stored in firebase I have that code but its not stored in firebase.

```
DropDownMultiSelect(
    onChanged: (membervalue){
    setState(() {                                                                 
          selectedMembertype =membervalue as String?;
      });
    }
```

options:

```
 ["Golden Members","Silver Members",],
 selectedValues: selected,
 whenEmpty: 'Select Member Type',                                                        
),
```

I want to store multiple values in firebase.

Comment: can you share your code? what have you tried yet? and what isn't working?

Comment: yeah i shared my code.

Comment: can you show the string you're trying to add onto the firestore? And also the code for firestore

Comment: Can you include the code you're using to store the data? There's a number of examples on the Flutter website [Write Data](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#writing-data)